# Age Classifier python program

Tags: python, syntax

```python
print("Welcome to the Age Classifier program")
person_age=(float(input("Enter the person's Age"))

if person_age<=1 or person_age>0:
        print("Person is an infant")
elif person_age>1 or person_age<13:
        print("Person is a child")
elif person_age>=13 or person_age<20:
        print("Person is a teenager")

elif person_age>=20 :
        print("Person is an adult")
else:
        print("Person has not been conceived or is developing in the womb")
```

When I execute this code, the interpreter reports that there is an error on the 1st line of the body of the `if` statements, with a message reporting that the syntax is invalid. I tried adding parenthesis and the same syntax error is encountered.

Comment: In this case, even if input is `-1`, output will be `"Person is an infant "`.

Answer (score 2):

The error in your first line is primarily due to the parenthesis:

```
person_age=(float(input("Enter the person's Age")) # 3 opening, 2 closing.
```

Change this to:

```
person_age=(float(input("Enter the person's Age")))
```

Also, you have a logical error. The `or` operator returns `True` if either of the conditions is True. I doubt that suits your use case. You should do something like:

```
if person_age<=1 and person_age>0:
        print("Person is an infant")
elif person_age>1 and person_age<13:
        print("Person is a child")
elif person_age>=13 and person_age<20:
        print("Person is a teenager")
elif person_age>=20 :
        print("Person is an adult")
else:
        print("Person has not been conceived or is developing in the womb")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have unbalanced parentheses.

```
person_age=float(input("Enter the person's Age"))
```

It would probably be a better idea, though, to make this an integer:

```
person_age=int(input("Enter the person's Age"))
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently floats don't take negative numbers

Comment: Glad we could help.